# Rambox stopped working

Tags: 18.04

I've been using Rambox CE for a while - mainly for SMS and WhatsApp.

This morning it just refused to launch. I rebooted, it still failed. I re-installed the app, it still won't launch.

Any ideas? I'm using 18.04 and guess there's a log file somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it installed via apt?
Maybe remove/move the config folder `~/.config/Rambox`, and then start the app again.

Comment: Thanks. I installed via the Ubuntu software app. I don't have ~/.config/Rambox. I have ~/snap/rambox but no config file or folder in there.

Comment: `sudo snap remove rambox`  then `rm ~/snap/rambox` and reinstall rambox

Comment: Thanks, but it still won't launch - either from the 'launch' button in the software centre or the dock icon that's still there from when it did work...